# How to download a large file with httplib2

Tags: python, httplib2

Is it possible to download a large file in chunks using httplib2. I am downloading files from a Google API, and in order to use the credentials from the google OAuth2WebServerFlow, I am bound to use httplib2.

At the moment I am doing:

```
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
    client_id=XXXX,
    client_secret=XXXX,
    scope=XYZ,
    redirect_uri=XYZ
)

credentials = flow.step2_exchange(oauth_code)

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

resp, content = self.http.request(url, "GET")
with open(file_name, 'wb') as fw:
    fw.write(content)
```

But the `content` variable can get more than 500MB.

Any way of reading the response in chunks?

Comment: Does it work? Do you get any errors?

Comment: It works, but its not ok to have 500MB variables

Comment: Under Python 3.4 this works: https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#examples

Comment: Does it have to be `httplib2`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16696317/831531

Comment: yes in order to use the authorization from google's oauth library

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do authorization with `requests`

Comment: @MartinTaleski: Certainly! See http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/

Comment: I've added the code used for google authentication. Its ment to work with httplib2, as specified in the google docs. I'll try the same with requests

Comment: If all you need is OAuth2 to google services, you can try https://github.com/maraujop/requests-oauth2

Answer (score 0):

You could consider [streaming_httplib2](https://github.com/madlag/streaming_httplib2), a fork of httplib2 with exactly that change in behaviour.

> in order to use the credentials from the google OAuth2WebServerFlow, I am bound to use httplib2.

If you need features that aren't available in httplib2, it's worth looking at how much work it would be to get your credential handling working with another HTTP library. It may be a good longer-term investment. (e.g. [How to download large file in python with requests.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/how-to-download-large-file-in-python-with-requests-py).)

Answer (score 0):

About reading response in chunks (works with httplib, must work with httplib2)

```
import httplib
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("google.com")
conn.request("GET", "/")
r1 = conn.getresponse()

try:
    print r1.fp.next()
    print r1.fp.next()
except:
    print "Exception handled!"
```

Note: `next()` may raise `StopIteration` exception, you need to handle it.

You can avoid calling `next()` like this

```
F=open("file.html","w")
for n in r1.fp:
    F.write(n)
    F.flush()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply oauth2client.client.Credentials to a urllib2 request.

First, obtain the `credentials` object. In your case, you're using:

```
credentials = flow.step2_exchange(oauth_code)
```

Now, use that object to get the auth headers and add them to the urllib2 request:

```
req = urllib2.Request(url)
auth_headers = {}
credentials.apply(auth_headers)
for k,v in auth_headers.iteritems():
  req.add_header(k,v)
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Now `resp` is a file-like object that you can use to read the contents of the URL